# Computing total power from $x$, $y$, $z$ components of Poynting vector

Tags: electromagnetism, coordinate-systems, poynting-vector

I have (real parts) of $x$, $y$, $z$ components of Poynting vectors on the surface of a sphere. Since the total outward power flow from the sphere involves integrating the normal component of a Poynting vector, I am wondering that how the $x$, $y$, $z$ Components of the Ponting vector can be utilized to setup an integral such that the integral calculates the total outward power flow from the surface of a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

The power flowing through the sphere is

$$P=\int \mathbf S\cdot \hat n\,dA$$

where $\mathbf S$ is the Poynting vector, $\hat n$ is a unit normal to the sphere, and $dA$ an infinitesimal area on the sphere. You can write $\hat n$ in Cartesian components so that you can easily compute the dot product with your Cartesian components of $\mathbf S$. Do the integration over the sphere in spherical coordinates and express the Cartesian components of $\hat n$ in terms of the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: First I want to clarify that when we talk about a unit normal vector 'n' in terms of Cartesian vector coordinates, is the equation (14) on this link (http://dslavsk.sites.luc.edu/courses/phys301/classnotes/surfacenormal.pdf)  that you are talking about? Should I employ that? Also, when I take dot product of S and unit normal vector 'n' in Cartesian components, I will get a numeric value, then how I can express it again in terms of angles theta and phi for integration (as you mentioned at the end of your answer)?

Comment: Here is how I am thinking about it after your comments :   S.n' =  [x,y,z].[Sin(theta)Cos(phi), Sin(theta)Sin(Phi), Cos(Phi)], and once I have numeric values from these dot products, I can multiply it with dA= r^2 *Sin(Theta)*dTheta*dPhi and integrate over theta = [0,180] and Phi = [0,360]. Correct?

Comment: The dot product won’t be a single numeric value. It will be a function of the two angles, with a numeric value at each point on the sphere. And $\mathbf S$ doesn’t have components $[x,y,z]$; it has components $[S_x,S_y,S_z]$ which in general can be functions of the two angles.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And what if I have the data in Theta and Phi components? Will it make the things easier?

Comment: $S_\theta$ and $S_\phi$ don’t contribute; they are orthogonal to $\hat n$ and represent energy flowing along the sphere rather than through it. Only $S_r$ matters.

Comment: Finally, I am evaluating the integral like this :
P.n = xsin(theta)cos(phi) + ysin(theta)sin(phi) + zcos(theta)
dS = r^2 * sin(theta)*dtheta*dphi
Total power = Integ (P.ndS)  with limits of phi = [0,2pi] and theta = [0,pi]   
where x,y,z are Poynting vector components in Watts/meter^2 that I have. Does all that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, but writing $x,y,z$ when you really mean $S_x,S_y,S_z$ is no way to communicate with physicists. :)  By the way, you can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) even in comments. It is very easy to learn, and your math will look as good as a textbook.